# Proving the area is irrational for triangle with integer vertices

Tags: vectors, triangles, inner-products, 3d, integers

**Question:**

> $A,B,C$ are three non-collinear points lying on a plane whose normal vector is $(\hat{i}+\hat{j}+\hat{k})$. If all the three coordinates of every point is an integer, then prove that the area of the triangle is necessarily an irrational number.

**My attempt:**

I don't understand how to do this problem. I know how such types of problems are dealt with in the [2D plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1213085/89548), but not in 3D space. Can anyone offer some help on the starting steps? Thanks!

Comment: Does it mean that the normal vector is $(1,1,1)$?

Comment: @Leo163 Yes, the normal vector of the plane on which points ABC lie is $(1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll show  that if three non-collinear points on the given plane have *rational*  coordinates, then the area of the triangle with those points as vertices is irrational.

Suppose $A',B',C'$ are three non-collinear points with rational coordinates on the given plane.

Let $G$ be the centroid of triangle $A'B'C'$.

Then $G = {\large{\frac{A'+B'+C'}{3}}}$, hence $G$ also has rational coordinates.

Let $A = A'-G,\;\;B=B'-G,\;\;C=C'-G$.

Then $A,B,C$ are nonzero (as vectors), have rational coordinates, and reside in the plane with equation
$$x+y+z = 0$$
so the normal vector of the plane is still the vector $n=\langle{1,1,1}\rangle$.

Since triangle $ABC$ is just a translation of triangle $A'B'C'$, the area stays the same.

Thus, it suffices to show the area of triangle $ABC$ is irrational.

But now we have $A + B + C = 0$, so $A = -B-C$.

Let $k\;$denote the area of triangle $ABC$. 
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;k
&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}|AB\times AC|\\[4pt]
&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}|(B-A)\times (C-A)|\\[4pt]
&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}|(2B+C)\times (2C+B)|\qquad\text{[since$\;A = -B - C$]}\\[4pt]
&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}|4B{\times}C\,+\,2B{\times}B\,+\,2C{\times}C\,+\,C{\times}B|\\[4pt]
&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}|4B{\times}C\,+\,C{\times}B|\\[4pt]
&={\small{\frac{1}{2}}}|3B{\times}C|\\[4pt]
&={\small{\frac{3}{2}}}|B{\times}C|\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so it suffices to show $|B\times C|$ is irrational.

But $B\times C$ is a nonzero vector with rational coordinates, and is parallel to $n$.

It follows that $B\times C = \langle{t,t,t}\rangle$, for some nonzero rational number $t$, hence $|B\times C| = \sqrt{3t^2} =  |t|\sqrt{3},\;$which is irrational.

Comment: A stronger result, that's awesome! "But now we have A+B+C=0" You've used the fact that the normal to the given plane is of the form $(k,k,k)$ (along the normal $(1,1,1)$). I was not sure if there was a stronger result in the first place, but now that there is, can you do an even stronger result for any given plane, i.e. one whose normal vector is any $(l,m,n)$, with $l\neq m\neq n$?

Comment: The proof goes through (essentially unchanged) for any normal vector $n=\langle{n_1,n_2,n_3}\rangle$ where $n_1,n_2,n_3$ are rational, and $n_1^2 + n_2^2 +n_3^2$ is not the square of a rational number.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try doing it on my own and let you know if I succeed

Comment: It's line by line essentially the same. Just replace $n = \langle{1,1,1}\rangle$ by $n = \langle{n_1,n_2,n_3}\rangle$.

Comment: Alright! I can't see easily how this swap doesn't invalidate the calculation of the cross product, but I'll try first and then comment.

Comment: The cross-product of two rational vectors is a rational vector (by using the algebraic formula). And $B{\times}C$ is still nonzero and parallel to $n$, so must have the form $\langle{tn_1,tn_2,tn_3}\rangle$, for some nonzero rational number $t$.

Answer (score 13):

I assume that the plane on which the points lay is normal to the vector $(1,1,1)$. After a translation, we can assume that one of the points is $(0,0,0)$ and the other two have integer coordinates: let them be $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$. Notice that the area of the triangle can be seen as the determinant of the matrix having as columns $(a,b,c)$, $(d,e,f)$ and $(1,1,1)$, divided by twice the length of $(1,1,1)$, since it is normal to the other two points (the idea is that you are calculating the volume of a solid having as base a quadrilateral having twice the area you are interested in). The determinant of a matrix with integer coefficients is integer, and the length of $(1,1,1)$ is $\sqrt{3}$. So the area is irrational.

Comment: Can you please explain how you say that the area of the triangle is a determinant? I haven't been taught any such formula yet.

Comment: It is a geometric way of seen the determinant: for example, in dimension 2, the determinant of a matrix having as columns the vectors $v$ and $w$ is the area of the quadrilateral having as vertices $0$, $v$, $w$ and $v+w$.

Comment: (Which e.g. explains why the determinant tells you if $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent: if they are on the same line, the quadrilateral is degenerate, and the area is $0$). This extends to higher dimensions, substituting "area" with "volume".

Comment: "the idea is that you are calculating the volume of a solid having as base a quadrilateral having twice the area you are interested in" I got it! The solid you've taken here is a quadrilateral base (on the triangle) with the height along the direction of the normal. You're dividing by length of $\sqrt{3}$ to get the base area. You're dividing by 2 to get area of triangle.

Comment: What an intriguing approach! I remember learning about vectors in pre-cal (before I really got to understand their beauty in physics), and one of the applications we learned was this triangle area formula. I thought the whole unit was confusing, but that formula seemed especially frivolous. Now I see how it’s useful! +1

Comment: Setting up this determinant formula has an easier explanation if you use the cross-product along the way.

Comment: If for some reason you are more familiar with cross products than with determinants, you can consider the vector $(a,b,c)\times (d,e,f)$. It has integer coordinates, and must be parallel with $(1,1,1)$. Then it is on the form $(n,n,n)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and has length $n\sqrt 3$ which is the area of the parallelogram. The triangle has area $\frac12 n\sqrt 3$. Of course this comment is very related to quasi's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\vec{AB}(a,b,c)$ and $\vec{AC}(p,q,r).$

Thus, $\{a,b,c,p,q,r\}\subset\mathbb Z$,  $a+b+c=p+q+r=0$ and
$$S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\cdot\sqrt{p^2+q^2+r^2}\cdot\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{ap+bq+cr}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\cdot\sqrt{p^2+q^2+r^2}}\right)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(p^2+q^2+r^2)-(ap+bq+cr)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4(a^2+ab+b^2)(p^2+pq+q^2)-(ap+bq+(a+b)(p+q))^2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3(aq-bp)^2}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}|aq-bp|\not\in\mathbb Q$$ and we are done!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Silly question I believe, but why is $a+b+c=0$? I was taught that the sum of the three vectors describing the sides of a triangle in order is zero. That means $\vec {AB}+\vec {BC}+\vec {CA}=0$. But how is $a+b+c+=0$?

Comment: It's $\vec{AB}\cdot(i+j+k)=\vec{AC}\cdot(i+j+k)=0$.

Comment: Understood, the sides of the triangle are perpendicular to the normal. I'll accept your answer in a day or two, provided there are no better other approaches. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! There is a proof by using value of tetrahedron, but for this we need matrices. .

Comment: I think if that's a second approach please do post it! I am familiar with operations on determinants and matrices.

Comment: @Gaurang Tandon We can calculate $\frac{1}{6}$ of the determinant of the matrices, about which  Leo163 says.

Comment: Yes, I later noticed you had looped back to that same method.

Comment: In case anyone else didn't recognize it, the formula being used for $S_{\triangle ABC}$ is $\dfrac{1}{2}(AB)(AC)\sin\theta$ (where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$), using $\sin\theta = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2\theta}$ and $\cos\theta = \dfrac{\vec{AB} \cdot \vec{AC}}{(AB)(AC)}$.